# Get hidden end segments of strava routes

Tags: strava, strava-api-v3

I'm pulling a list of activities from the Strava v3 API `/athlete/activities` endpoint and displaying the routes on a map.
Initially I'm using the `activity.map.summary_polyline` to draw to my map but this does not include the start and end portions that are hidden due to user privacy settings.

The only way I can find to get the complete route data is to loop over all the activities once they are received, get their ids and then individually call `/activities/{id}`.
This returns more detail and includes `activity.map.polyline` which displays correctly but seems like a lot of additional calls - basically loading every activity twice.

Is there a way to get the `summary_polyline` to include the hidden route portions?
Or some way to get `/athlete/activities` to include the more detailed `polyline` property in its return?